# How to sync Netsuite CRM with database?

Tags: synchronization, netsuite

I have done CRUD operations in Netsuite using RESTlet.

After deleting the record using RESTlet, I can update my database by code.

But if the user will delete the contacts directly from GUI, I don't know how to delete the particular (deleted records in Netsuite) records in my database. So i need a code to synchronize the contacts of Netsuite with the database.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the record deletion code of your database in your User Event script, which, would fire whether you delete from Restlet or UI.

If record deletion from database is a time consuming process, better would be to fire a Scheduled script from your user event script on delete event which would then do the synchronization/deletion process from DB.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I pass values from a PHP script to RESTlet file to delete the record using Oauth. After deleting I could get deleted id by which I can delete a record stored in my local DB. But how can i delete record from my local DB when deletes record from GUI. I could understand the flow that is [Deletion in GUI mode -> trigger event script -> trigger scheduled script]. By this way how to synchronize?

Comment: Use the same code as it is in your restlet to delete record from db